# why double click a input element will trigger keyup event?

Tags: jquery, double-click, keyup

bind a keyup handler for a input use jquery,see:
[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/flowerszhong/evuAx/) in chrome version 22.0.1229.94 m

```
<input type="text" value="" id="test">
```

bind event handler:

```
$(function (argument) {
    var input = $("#test");
    input.bind("keyup",function(e){
      console.log("keyCode: " + e.keyCode);
      console.log("which: " + e.which);
    });
   })
```

when double click this input,will trigger the keyup-handler and output:

```
keyCode: 67 
which: 67 
keyCode: 17 
which: 17
```

any guy tell me why?

Comment: Does this happen in a specific browser?  What version of jQuery?  Tested on JSFiddle with Chrome and it looks fine to me.  If you can provide a JSFiddle that reproduces the error, that would help people help you.

Comment: @dherman I just test it in chrome 22.0.1229.94 m, JSFiddle link:http://jsfiddle.net/flowerszhong/evuAx/8/

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue on the same version of Chrome. Could be your computer. Have you tried this on any other computer?

Comment: @Abhilash I try it in other computer and the issue keep same;

Comment: What about other browsers? Is this issue coming? Bcoz, i also test this with _Version 22.0.1229.94 m_, it's working fine for me..

Comment: @ManikandanSethuraju Other browsers are ok!

Comment: @flowerszhong : Just use _$("#output").html(str);_ instead of _$("#output").append(str);_ & check

Comment: _17_ is key of _ctrl_ & _67_ is the key of _c_

Comment: @dherman Omg,there is a software named "youdao dict" disturb the input; I am so sorry to waste u time

Comment: @ManikandanSethuraju Omg,there is a software named "youdao dict" disturb the input; I am so sorry to waste u time

Answer (score 1):

Oh sorry, there was a software named "youdao dict" disturbing the user input and triggering the event.

Comment: My english is so poor,I use it to translate some words;

Answer (score 1):

I also have this problem. But actually when I quit my "youdao dict" software, this problem no longer happen again. You can see whether you have this software or others like this on you computer. Try to quit it.